# Android applications can't upload photos to the server

Tags: android, tomcat

I want to do an App. It can realize to upload the phone picture to server. Now it can take the picture and save to the mobile phone. But it can not upload into server. How to deal with this? The server is using tomcat to setup.

Android upload code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class uploadActivity extends Activity
{
private Button uploadbutton;
private String uploadFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Test.jpg";
private String srcPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Test.jpg";
private String actionUrl = "http://192.168.1.105:8080/ATestInternetCameraServlet/";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);
uploadbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
uploadbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)
{
uploadFile();
}
});
    }
 private void uploadFile()
  { String uploadUrl = "http://192.168.1.105:8080/ATestInternetCameraServlet/CameraServlet";
    String end = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "******";
    try
    {
      URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
      HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
          .openConnection();
      httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
      httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
      httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
      httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
      httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");
      httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
          "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
      DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection
          .getOutputStream());
      dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + end);
      dos
          .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""
              + srcPath.substring(srcPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
              + "\"" + end);
      dos.writeBytes(end);
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcPath); 
      byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // 8k
      int count = 0;
      while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)
      {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
      }
      fis.close();
      dos.writeBytes(end);
      dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + end);
      dos.flush();
      InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String result = br.readLine();
      Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//
      dos.close();
      is.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      setTitle(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

The server code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class CameraServlet extends HttpServlet
{
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
try
{
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8"); 
PrintWriter out2 = response.getWriter();

        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(); 
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);        
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
         String uploadPath = "d:\\cameraupload\\";
        File file = new File(uploadPath);
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        String filename = ""; 
        InputStream is = null; 
                for (FileItem item : items)
        {

            if (item.isFormField())
            {
                if (item.getFieldName().equals("filename"))
                {
                                        if (!item.getString().equals(""))
                        filename = item.getString("UTF-8");
                }
            }
                        else if (item.getName() != null && !item.getName().equals(""))
            {
                              filename = item.getName().substring(
                        item.getName().lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                is = item.getInputStream(); // 得到上传文件的InputStream对象
            }
        }
               filename = uploadPath + filename;
                if (new File(filename).exists())
        {
            new File(filename).delete();
        }
        // Began to upload files
        if (!filename.equals(""))
        {
            // use FileOutputStream to open the upload file in server
            FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; 
            int count = 0;
            // Began to read the upload file in bytes，and input it to server's upload file output stream
            while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                fos2.write(buffer, 0, count); // To write the byte stream server files
            }
            fos2.close(); // close FileOutputStream object
            is.close(); // InputStream object
            out2.println("file upload success!xii");

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: `http://192.168.1.105:8080/ATestInternetCameraServlet/CameraServlet` it's not loading at my side. please check it in browser

Comment: You really should respond to the answers given to your question. Was any of them helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error tracing?? Our just happening nothing??

For using httpurlconnection, you need to change the policy at the beginning:

```
ThreadPolicy mThreadPolicy = new ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(mThreadPolicy);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...add apache-mime4j-0.6.jar and httpmime-4.0.3.jar libs

```
      File f=new File(exsistingFileName);
      HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.105:8080/ATestInternetCameraServlet/CameraServlet");
 MultipartEntity Mentity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
String url1=exsistingFileName;
 String mime;

    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url1);
    if (extension != ""&&extension!=null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime1 = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        mime = mime1.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    else
    {
            String ext = url1.substring((url1.lastIndexOf(".") + 1), url1.length());
            MimeTypeMap mime1 = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            mime = mime1.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
    }


 ContentBody cbFile;
 if(mime!=null)
     cbFile= new FileBody(f,mime);
 else
     cbFile=new FileBody(f);
 Mentity.addPart("file",cbFile);
post.setEntity(Mentity);
 HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    response = http.execute(post);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().
       handleResponse(response);
} catch (HttpResponseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

     System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
     System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
     if (entity != null) {
         System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't 192.168.1.105 an IP-adress on the local network? Are you sure it's reachable from your phone? Open your phone's browser and try to navigate to the URL, can you reach it?

At what end are you having problems with the upload? Client or server? If it's on the client, what error are you getting? Or is it silently failing? Have you tried to make a simple HTML form and do the upload from there? If that is working you know it's your Android code that is the problem?

Also, it hurts every time I see someone trying to implement file uploads on their own. I'm not saying that your code is wrong, but it's an awful lot of lines of code (thus more risk of errors) compared to if you'd use a 3rd party library to abstract away all of that code for you. A well known and popular library such as [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) has good support for file uploads out of the box:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
String filename = "file.png";
File myFile = new File("/path/to/" + filename);
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("file", myFile);
    params.put("filename", filename);
    client.post("http://192.168.1.105:8080/ATestInternetCameraServlet/CameraServlet", params, responseHandler);
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle
}
```